# 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurrs in mscorlib.dll and The thread '<No Name>' (0x11a8) has exited with code 0 (0x0)

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, threadabortexception

I have got Four databases of students,faculty,non-faculty and admin, on login page i have a user id and password textbox for inputs plus the user type drop down list...where i add session of their names on login page which shows apparently when i debug.write it in my output console and also on masterpage, it shows the names of all four users, thus i guess the session is created there too...my masterpage code is as below:

```
if (Session["StudFirstName"] != null)
    {
        Label1.Text = Session["StudId"].ToString();
    }

    if (Session["FacultyFirstName"] != null)
    {
        Label1.Text = Session["StudId"].ToString();
    }
    if (Session["AccEmployeeName"] != null)
    {
        Label1.Text = Session["StudId"].ToString();
    }
    if (Session["AdminName"] != null)
    {
        Label1.Text = Session["StudId"].ToString();
    }

    else
    {
        Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
    }
```

But when i run it on browser, and hit submit on login page, as i said session is created but the page never goes to masterpage, it just refreshes and come to login itself, i have tried to clear nullexceptions too...how can i solve this exception ?? and ask me if u need any more information.... :)

herez my submit button code :

```
if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text == "Student")
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select StudFirstName from Student where StudId=@sid and Password=@pw", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sid", TextBox1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pw", TextBox2.Text);
        con.Open();
        string name = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
        con.Close();

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
            Label1.Text = "Sorry! Invalid User ID or Password!";
        else
        {
            if (CheckBox1.Checked)
            {
                Response.Cookies["UName"].Value = TextBox1.Text;
                Response.Cookies["PWD"].Value = TextBox2.Text;
                Response.Cookies["UName"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(2);
                Response.Cookies["PWD"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(2);
            }

            Session.Add("studid", TextBox1.Text);
            Session.Add("studfirstname", name);
            FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(name, false);
            Debug.Write(Session["studfirstname"].ToString());
        }

}







     if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text == "Faculty Staff")
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select FacultyFirstName from Faculty where FacultyId=@fid and Password=@pw", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fid", TextBox1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pw", TextBox2.Text);
        con.Open();
        string name = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
        con.Close();
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
            Label1.Text = "Sorry! Invalid User ID or Password!";
        else
        {
            if (CheckBox1.Checked)
            {
                Response.Cookies["UName"].Value = TextBox1.Text;
                Response.Cookies["PWD"].Value = TextBox2.Text;
                Response.Cookies["UName"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(2);
                Response.Cookies["PWD"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(2);
            }
            Session["FacultyId"] = TextBox1.Text;
            Session.Add("FacultyFisrtName", name);
            FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(name, false);
            Debug.Write(Session["FacultyFisrtName"].ToString());
        }
    }
    if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text == "Non-Faculty Staff")
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select AccEmployeeName from AccEmployee where AccEmployeeId=@aid and Password=@pw", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aid", TextBox1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pw", TextBox2.Text);
        con.Open();
        string name = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
        con.Close();
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
            Label1.Text = "Sorry! Invalid User ID or Password!";
        else
        {
            if (CheckBox1.Checked)
            {
                Response.Cookies["UName"].Value = TextBox1.Text;
                Response.Cookies["PWD"].Value = TextBox2.Text;
                Response.Cookies["UName"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(2);
                Response.Cookies["PWD"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(2);
            }
            Session["AccEmployeeFacultyId"] = TextBox1.Text;
            Session.Add("AccEmployeeName", name);
            FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(name, false);
            Debug.Write(Session["AccEmployeeName"].ToString());
        }
    }
    if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text == "Admin")
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select AdminName from Admin where AdminId=@pid and Password=@pw", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pid", TextBox1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pw", TextBox2.Text);
        con.Open();
        string name = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
        con.Close();
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
            Label1.Text = "Sorry! Invalid User ID or Password!";
        else
        {
            if (CheckBox1.Checked)
            {
                Response.Cookies["UName"].Value = TextBox1.Text;
                Response.Cookies["PWD"].Value = TextBox2.Text;
                Response.Cookies["UName"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(2);
                Response.Cookies["PWD"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(2);
            }
            Session["AdminId"] = TextBox1.Text;
            Session.Add("AdminName", name);
            FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(name, false);
            Debug.Write(Session["AdminName"].ToString());
                        }
    }
```

Comment: Is the code you posted from when you hit the submit button?

Comment: no....it's the code on masterpage...where this submit must go to....but wait i'm giving you my submit button code in few seconds plz..